# MongoDB Push Object into Array

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a problem with **MongoDB**.

Now I tried to push an object into my array but my code doesn't work.
Please help.

```
if (mongoQuantity != quantity)
  {
  var update1 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Push("Attribute." + colorcode +".Beden.$.Quantity", quantity);
  var result1 = Xml.UpdateOne(quizUpdateFilter, update1);
  }
```

[Here is my MongoDB document image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvvBz.png)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Is there an error, exception, database crash?

Comment: Can't find an object in my array.

Comment: Is `Beden.Quantity` an array?

Comment: Can you look picture. I added in the description.

Comment: Yes, I already looked at it.  I was trying to tactfully draw your attention there so you could note that you are trying to push one integer into another integer.  As noted in the $push docs, If the field is not an array, the operation will fail.

Comment: But my **Beden** field is an array

Comment: The field you are updating is Beden.Quantity.  The $ positional operator will select a single element from the Beden array to apply the update to.

Comment: Okay, but I need to push an object in the **Beden** array how can I do it? 
Like: Beden.$[].Quantity?

Comment: perhaps showing a sample object before and after the desired update would help clarify?

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks for your help :)